# Multiple Classloaders and Singletons

Tags: java, singleton, classloader

I recently learned that a java program can have multiple class loaders. I found some StackOverflow posts that explained how to create singleton objects.

The common approach was something like this:

```
if (instance == null) {
      ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      if (classLoader == null) {
        classLoader = Singleton.class.getClassLoader();
      }
      Class<?> sclass = (classLoader.loadClass(Singleton.class.getCanonicalName()));
}
```

I don't quite understand how this gets rid of the issue of multiple classloaders. If you have multiple ClassLoaders, the instance will be null when each of them tries to load the class. Isn't that correct? I would find it helpful if I could get a brief explanation on how this works.

Also, at what point are we able to retrieve the actual Singleton instance? I could do something like `instance = (Singleton) sclass.newInstance();` but that would be creating a new instance for each `ClassLoader`.

Comment: `I don't quite understand how this gets rid of the issue of multiple classloaders. ` What is the issue of multiple class loaders?  
If you have deliberately used multiple class loaders it is because they are what you needed and they are not the issue.  Which instance will be `null`?  This code gets a class with the same name as the Singleton class, but in the current threads class loader.

Answer (score 0):

> how this gets rid of the issue of multiple classloaders.

I don't see which issue you are referring to, but it doesn't get rid of any issues.

> the instance will be null when each of them tries to load the class.

The instance won't be null.

> we able to retrieve the actual Singleton instance?

When the thread has the desired ClassLoader, you can obtain teh SIngleton instance with either.

```
Singleton s = Singleton.INSTANCE;
```

or

```
Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
```

depending on how you normally access a Singleton.  if you need a singelton in another ClassLoader, you have to do the same except via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of this but they seem to be copied from an article on [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2).

It doesn't get rid of an issue with multiple classloaders. You can still have multiple instances.

It tries to load the class through the thread-context classloader. The problem is that you can't rely on this being any particular classloader, or the same for every thread, or place where this is called. If this is not available, then it tries, `Singleton.class.getClassLoader()` which is the classloader that would be used anyway, and is not guaranteed to be the same each time.

If the context classloader was always the same, then you would get the same instance each time, but you'd need to access this instance via reflection. You can't cast it to the correct type or you'd get a `ClassCastException` because the classloader that loaded the class wouldn't match the current one.

Here is an example demonstrating the usage of the `getClass` method, using the ByteBuddy library to create the classloaders:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run();
        run();
    }

    public static void run() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader parent = Main.class.getClassLoader();

        byte[] runnerBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File("/path/to/bin/Runner.class").toPath());
        byte[] singletonBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File("/path/to/bin/Singleton.class").toPath());

        Map<String, byte[]> classes = new HashMap<>();
        classes.put("Runner", runnerBytes);
        classes.put("Singleton", singletonBytes);

        ByteArrayClassLoader classLoader = new ByteArrayClassLoader.ChildFirst(
            parent,
            classes,
            null,
            ByteArrayClassLoader.PersistenceHandler.MANIFEST,
            PackageDefinitionStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE
        );

        Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass("Runner");

        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
        Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
        clazz.getMethod("run").invoke(instance);
    }
}

public class Runner {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Object instance = getClass("Singleton").getMethod("getInstance").invoke(null);
            Object result = instance.getClass().getMethod("getValue").invoke(instance);
            System.out.println("RESULT: " + result);
        } catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Class<?> getClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if(classLoader == null) {
            classLoader = Singleton.class.getClassLoader();
        }
        return (classLoader.loadClass(className));
    }
}

public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private double value = Math.random();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
RESULT: 0.8998675708591397
RESULT: 0.7230302140857906
```

So this does not create the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the common approach to create singleton objects.

The common egar approach is this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass();
    private SomeClass() {}
}
```

If you want lazy it's like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static SomeClass instance;
    private SomeClass() {}
    public static SomeClass getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new SomeClass();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Where it is true that the static code is ran when the class gets loaded by the class loader.  And it is possible that the class could be loaded by multiple class loaders.  In most cases this, by convention, should be impossible.  Class loaders if implemented correctly should ask their parent to load the class before they attempt to try.  In your case if the context class loader is a child of the base class loader, your Singleton.class should be the exact same class, regardless of which classloader you ask.

Having said this, there are a few classloaders that break that convention, infamously the Tomcat classloaders.  You can get some really weird stuff that happens when classloaders break this rule.  For instance two classes with the same name, and byte code not equal each other.  Meaning if one object was instantiated using one class loader and anther was instantiated with another class loader, even if they had the same value(their .equals() method should return true) it wont because their classes don't match.  The instanceof will not work, if you were to bypass the instance of and just cast it, it would throw a ClassCastException.

The bottom line here is you got bigger problems then having multiple singleton instances.

> instance = (Singleton) sclass.newInstance();

This is tricky,  because if sclass.newInstance() did return a different class(or one that was loaded by a different classloader) than your Singleton when you attempt to cast here you would get a ClassCastException, because they are different classes.